# Return all files within a folder using Google Drive Java API

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm able to retrieve all the files inside of my root folder using this code:

```
FileList result = driveService.files().list()
        .setPageSize(100)
        .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
        .execute();
```

However I would like to return only the files inside the "test" folder under root, but this fails:

```
FileList result = driveService.files().list().setQ("test in parents")
            .setPageSize(100)
            .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
            .execute();
```

with this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=nextPageToken,%20files(id,%20name)&pageSize=100&q=test%20in%20parents
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "q",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think it needs to be `'test' in parents`. You forgot the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the quotes around `test`.

And `test` cannot be the folder name, but the folder id.

> 'FOLDER_ID' in parents

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files: Fields](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref#fields)
- [Query string examples](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#query_string_examples)

Comment: Thanks, however this seems very convoluted.. Do I first have to query for the folder name in order to get the id and then do another query to get the files?

Comment: @user2395365 That's correct, you cannot list directly via parent folder name. You have to get the folder id first, which you can get with a previous query as you said.